# Annotate query for calculate sum of 2 table value with Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 tables

```
Class Billing(models.Model):
 id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 .....
 #Some more fields
 ....


Class BillInfo(models.Model):
  id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  billing=models.ForeignKey(Billing)
  testId=models.ForeignKey(AllTests)
  costOfTest=models.IntegerField(default=0)
  concession=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here `BillInfo` is verticle table i.e one `Billing` has multiple `BillInfo`. Here I want to calculate the `Sum(costOfTest - concession)` for a single `Billing`.

Can I achieve this using single query?

Need help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `ForeignKey` from `BillInfo` to `Billing`?

Comment: Yes, question updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Billing.objects.annotate(
    the_sum=Sum(F('billinfo__costOfTest') - F('billinfo__concession'))
)
```

Here every `Billing` object in this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.the_sum` which is the sum of all `costOfTest`s minus the `concession` of all *related* `BillingInfo` objects.

The SQL query that calculates this will look, approximately as:

```
SELECT billing.*
       SUM(billinginfo.costOfTest - billinginfo.concession) AS the_sum
FROM billing
LEFT OUTER JOIN billinginfo ON billinginfo.billing_id = billing.id
GROUP BY billing.id
```

So when you "materialize" the query, the query will obtain the sum for *all* the `Billing` objects in a single call.

For `Billing` objects without any related `BillingInfo`, the `the_sum` attribute will be `None`, we can avoid that by using the [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) function:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Billing.objects.annotate(
    the_sum=Coalesce(
        Sum(F('billinfo__costOfTest') - F('billinfo__concession')),
        Value(0)
    )
)
```

Comment: `BillingInfo` has `Billing` as a `ForeignKey`.

Getting error

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'billinfo' into field.`

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI: indeed, and as you can see in the query, we make use of the `billing_id` counterpart of this foreign key in the `JOIN`.

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI: the point is that if you define a `ForeignKey` from model `A` to `B`, Django constructs an *implicit* relation that refers from `B` to `A`.

Comment: But I want to access the `BillInfo` from the `Billing` model and `Billing` is ForeignKey of `BillInfo`. There is an object `billinginfo_set`.

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI: we *are* accessing the `BillingInfo` from the `Billing`. Notice the `F('billinginfo__...')`. The fact that the `ForeignKey` is located otherwise does *not* matter, since a database makes a `JOIN` and will normally have a proper index to do this properly. It is not because there is no *explicit* `ForeignKey` stored in the database that this is a problem to obtain the set of *related* `BillingInfo`.